# Hankel Transform integrals won't work in Mathematica

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

I'm trying to do this integral, [which is shown on the Wikipedia page on the Hankel transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hankel_transform):

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\mathrm d\varphi\;e^{\mathrm im\varphi}e^{\mathrm ikr\cos(\varphi)}$$

The answer is supposed to be

$$2\pi\mathrm i^m J_m(kr)$$

Mathematica cannot seem to do this integral; it simply gives me the input back:

```
Integrate[
    Exp[I m phi] Exp[I k r Cos[phi]],
    {phi, 0, 2 Pi},
    Assumptions -> Element[m, Integers]
]
```

Why can't this be done? It can do it for explicit values of m = 0 and m = 1, but after that it begins reporting the answer in terms of polynomials times a zero-order Bessel function or something similar. Perhaps I'm expecting too much of the software, but I'd expect it to be able to verify integrals listed on Wikipedia pages. Is there something I'm overlooking?

Comment: I've had problems like this. If you only want to verify the known result, have you tried evaluating "Integral minus solution", to see if it simplifies to zero?

Comment: I will wager that the reluctance of *Mathematica* to evaluate your integral *generically* is due to the differing behavior of the integral of the *components* `Cos[m phi + k r Cos[phi]]` and `Sin[m phi + k r Cos[phi]]`, depending on whether `m` is odd or even. Try executing `Assuming[k > 0 && r > 0, Table[Integrate[{Cos[m phi + k r Cos[phi]], Sin[m phi + k r Cos[phi]]}, {phi, 0, 2 Pi}], {m, 0, 5}]]`, for instance.

Comment: "...after that it begins reporting the answer in terms of polynomials times a zero-order Bessel function or something similar." - yes, because it seems that *Mathematica* internally uses [the recursion formulae for Bessel function](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.6.E1) within `Integrate[]` to simplify things. Unfortunately, it looks as if `FullSimplify[]` is ignorant of this very recursion formula, so...

Answer (score 13):

The answer is simply that integrating with the assumption that a variable comes from the class of integers is **really** difficult. What `Integrate` does with `Assumptions -> Element[m, Integers]` is try to generically integrate without the assumption and then apply the assumption to the result to try and simplify it. I've asked around about this before and there doesn't seem to be a good way to make a generic algorithm that actually handles assumptions like `Element[m, Integers]`.

You can find many cases where `Assumptions -> Element[something, Integers]` doesn't produce the expected simplification. Most of the cases I've seen of integrals where a variable is assumed to be an integer are where the integrand is the product of two orthogonal functions. In these cases,the way these are solved on paper doesn't generalize easily.