# Integrating over Bessel Function erroneous? (Hankel Transform)

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs, special-functions, integral-transforms

**Bug introduced in 8.0.4 or earlier and persists through 11.0.1 or later**

---

The Hankel Transform is given by

```
Integrate[f[x] x BesselJ[0, x t], {x, 0, Infinity}]
```

It is self-inverse, so

```
Integrate[F[t] t BesselJ[0, x t], {t, 0, Infinity}]
```

gives the back-transformation.

I tried out a simple case:

```
Integrate[UnitBox[x/2] x BesselJ[0, x t], {x, 0, Infinity}]
```

which promptly results in

```
BesselJ[1, t]/t
```

This is correct. However, if I do the back-transformation:

```
Integrate[BesselJ[1, t]/t t BesselJ[0, x t], {t, 0, Infinity}]
```

the integration takes noticeably longer (which is expected since the function oscillates) and the result is

```
ConditionalExpression[0, x>1]
```

While that single condition would be correct - `UnitBox[x/2] == 0` for `x > 1` - the rest of the function won't show up.

Is there any way to make the obviously missing parts show up?

Related but not quite what I'm asking:
[Hankel Transform integrals won't work in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1979) 
[Strange result when integrating BesselJ functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7986)

Comment: ```Integrate[BesselJ[1, t]/t t BesselJ[0, x t], {t, 0, Infinity}]``` in 11.3, returns this `int doesn't coverage`, and returns back origin formula.

Answer (score 3):

Try :

```
Integrate[BesselJ[1, t]/t t BesselJ[0, x t], {t, 0, Infinity}, 
   Assumptions -> { x > 0}]
```

Comment: Why not `Integrate[BesselJ[1, t]  BesselJ[0, x t], {t, 0, Infinity}, Assumptions -> {x > 0}]`?

Comment: That apparently works. Weird. I think I previously had a case where it didn't.

Comment: @m_goldberg of course, that bit of simplifying would make it a bit faster but it's less general. I had this problem with more complex functions as input as well. Ones that wouldn't simplify so readily.

Comment: `Integrate[(Sin[t]-t Cos[t])/t^2 BesselJ[0,t x],{t,0,Infinity},Assumptions->x>0]` should return something equivalent to `UnitBox[x/2]Sqrt[1-x^2]` (at least for x>0) but doesn't get evaluated at all. Without assumptions, it returns `ConditionalExpression[0,x>1 || x<-1]` - basically the same problem but not fixable with that simple assumption.